# Remove old records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

I have records of the following type in Mongo DB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50217d8874ebb0e4e52cc07d"),   
    "timestamp" : "8/7/12 1:41:36 PM Pacific Daylight Time",
    "_ts" : ISODate("2012-08-07T20:41:44.119Z")
}
```

How do I remove old records? I have tried something like `db.offlineLogs.remove({timestamp: {$lt:new Date("2012, 8, 3")}});`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original query, `timestamp` is simply a string field and `Date()` will be treated as a string in the Mongo shell. Comparing those operands will work like any other string comparison:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc1-pre-
connecting to: test
> db.foo.drop()
true
> db.foo.insert({ x: Date() });
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218e808930273947a21cf3"), "x" : "Tue Aug 07 2012 17:54:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
> sleep(1000)
null
> db.foo.find({ x: { $lt: Date() }});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218e808930273947a21cf3"), "x" : "Tue Aug 07 2012 17:54:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
> db.foo.find({ x: { $gt: Date() }});
>
```

`ISODate()` is the JS equivalent for [Mongo date fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates), and it is not comparable with string values when using the `$gt` or `$lt` operators:

```
> db.foo.find({ x: { $gt: ISODate() }});
> db.foo.find({ x: { $lt: ISODate() }});
> db.foo.find({ x: { $ne: ISODate() }});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218e808930273947a21cf3"), "x" : "Tue Aug 07 2012 17:54:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
> db.foo.insert({x: ISODate() });
> db.foo.find({ x: {$gt: Date() }});
> db.foo.find({ x: {$lt: Date() }});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218e808930273947a21cf3"), "x" : "Tue Aug 07 2012 17:54:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
> db.foo.find({ x: {$ne: Date() }});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218e808930273947a21cf3"), "x" : "Tue Aug 07 2012 17:54:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50218fa18930273947a21cf4"), "x" : ISODate("2012-08-07T21:58:57.350Z") }
>
```

Mongo does define [compare orders between types](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/What+is+the+Compare+Order+for+BSON+Types), in which strings come before dates, but that relates to sort order when the same field may have different types across the collection.

Note that if removal of old records if something you envision yourself doing often (e.g. in a batch process), you may be interested in [TTL collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), which are a new feature in the upcoming 2.2 release. Kristina Chodorow also wrote an amusing introduction on the topic in [this blog entry](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/25933713094/good-night-westley-time-to-live-collections).

Answer (score 6):

Resolved it using this: `db.offlineLogs.remove({"_ts":{"$lt":ISODate("2012-08-01T19:30:07.805Z")}});`

Answer (score 3):

You might also check on [using TimeToLive](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

MongoDB has a feature `TimeToLive` where you can specify how long you would like a document to be present in a collection before it is automatically deleted.

For example, assume you have a collection named billing with the following fields:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a05ef17055161ef66e9b21"), 
    "receiptId" : NumberInt(31124124), 
    "salesperson" : "jack", 
    "salesTime" : ISODate("2017-08-25T17:32:23.157+0000")
}
```

You can create a index on this collection like:

```
db.billing.createIndex( { "salesTime": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 });
```

This will make any document in the collection to be deleted after one hour (3600 seconds) based on the salesTime field.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: While it's nice to have more context, the [canonical NAA guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) explicitly does not label anything "NAA" if it has the actual name of the basic code element being recommended. Don't flag this type of answer in the future.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: VLQ, then? I noticed the automated downvote when I edited. But VLQ is even less justifiable. (Making assumptions about someone flagging when using a canned autocomment is perfectly reasonable behavior in general.)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: No, it was [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), which automatically issues a downvote when a VLQ/NAA flag is disputed via edit.